# jQuery Accordion not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having difficulty getting a jqueryui accordion to function. Even copying the example from the jquery website into jsfiddle it still doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Viewable in jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FYrBS/103/

Comment: The path to the jQuery UI .js file in your fiddle isn't valid. Fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FYrBS/106/

Comment: you have not included jquery ui so check this one http://jsfiddle.net/97KEE/

Comment: Ha, epic fail on my part, I see now I cut off some when I copy & pasted the URL for jquery ui :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the head. It is working Here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the JQuery UI. Below is the CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>​
```